# Trying to loop rows of another Workbook's sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Workbooks where I need to compare ID's from the one where I write the script and to other one I need to access from the script.

I loop through all numbers in sheet and record each ID in "tmpFisNo".  After that I make one loop for iterating through other Workbook's rows and compare them.

However, it says "Mismatch Error" in line `For j = ws.Cells(9, 9).Value To ws.Cells(10, 9).Value`

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim tmpFisNo As String
Dim tmpFisNo2 As String

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sub Dogrula_Click()
    wbPath = Cells(8, 9).Value
    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("2015_OCAK_MUTABAKAT_RAPORU")

    Set ws = wbTarget.Sheets(2)


    For i = Cells(5, 9).Value To Cells(6, 9).Value

        tmpFisNo = Cells(i, 2).Text
        For j = ws.Cells(9, 9).Value To ws.Cells(10, 9).Value
            tmpFisNo2 = ws.Cells(j, 4).Text
            If tmpFisNo = tmpFisNo2 Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Properly qualify your references, I'd put a considerable amount of money on your code failing because `Cells(5, 9).Value` isn't looking where you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tmpFisNo As String
Dim tmpFisNo2 As String

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sub Dogrula_Click()
    wbPath = Cells(8, 9).Value
    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("2015_OCAK_MUTABAKAT_RAPORU")

    Set ws = wbTarget.Sheets(2)


    For i = Cells(5, 9).Value To Cells(6, 9).Value

        tmpFisNo = Cells(i, 2).Text
        dim a as Long, b as Long
        a = CLng(ws.Cells(9, 9).Value)
        b = CLng(ws.Cells(10, 9).Value)
        For j = a To b
            tmpFisNo2 = ws.Cells(j, 4).Text
            If tmpFisNo = tmpFisNo2 Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

If it gives you an error on the CLngs then it's because you have some values in the spreadsheet in cells (9,9) or (10,9) which aren't integers

I would also recommend using Long instead of Integer - you can't reach all the cells in the worksheet using Integer (even for the old versions of Excel)

Comment: Okey I think it worked now. However I have couple of questions :
1) Do I need to do anything when I set wbTarget to other workbook? Because I didn't understand what Activate function doing?

Comment: The Activate function serves two purposes: i) brings the book/sheet you're activating to the front of the screen and ii) subsequent code like Cells(i,7).Value = i in your code go to the ActiveSheet in the ActiveWorkbook . To put them elsewhere you need code like ws.Cells(j, 4) = x